# Hibernate ManyToMany

Tags: hibernate

Context:
I have two tables Secret_Agent and Secret_Mission. Both have a `@ManyToMany` relationship with each other since many secret agents can be given to perform the same secret mission and the same secret agent can be given many secret missions.

```
Table SECRET_AGENT

Columns SecretAgentId, SecrentAgentName

Table SECRET_MISSION

Columns SecretMissionId, SecrentMissionName

JOIN Table

SECRET_AGENT_MISSION

Columns: SecretAgentId,SecretMissionId
```

Java Code:

```
class Secret_Agent {
.
.
.

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "SECRET_AGENT_MISSION", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "SecretAgentId") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "SecretMissionId") }
private List <Secret_Mission> missions;
.
.
.
}

class Secret_Mission {
.
.
.

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "missions")
private List <Secret_Agent> agents;
.
.
.
}
```

Problem:
I am trying to fetch all secret agents who do not have a secret mission assigned through Hibernate Criteria in the below mentioned code:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Secret_Agent.class);

criteria.add(Restrictions.isNull("missions"));
```

However, it doesn't work. I am trying my luck with Projections and QBE meanwhile.

Another way is to use the Crieteria Association, but Association would work only with `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne`!

Please help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your mapping is correct: use `Restrictions.isEmpty("missions") - Constrain a collection valued property to be empty` (from javadoc)

PS: In Hibernate is best pratice to init collection in mapping as:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "SECRET_AGENT_MISSION", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "SecretAgentId") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "SecretMissionId") }
private List <Secret_Mission> missions = new ArrayList<Secret_Mission>();
```

and do the same for `Secret_Agent.agents`

Comment: bellabax: Thanks, I'll chekc it out. Mapping is correct. Since I am using an internet system far away from my workstation due to iSecurity reasons, I can't write the whole code ditto and need to present it in general world entities rather than my own entities used in project